# Retrieve current share from linkedin

Tags: android

I am using `linkedin-j-android.jar`, it is working perfectly. I have succeed to retrieve user connections, name, last name etc. But  when I am trying to retrieve the user's current share, it is returning null.

I am using following code:

```
Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
CurrentShare share= p.getCurrentShare();
```

Is there any clue?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to this open [issue](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/issues/detail?id=78).